# How to Replace the AzureRM module with Az in Azure Automation Account

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-automation, powershell-ise, az

I'm trying to use Azure Automation Account to run some jobs, but I'm struggling with the AzureRM Module installed. I manually installed some Az Modules but PowerShell ISE still using the AzureRM, like in trying to establish RunAs connectio below,

```
$RunAsConnection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name AzureRunAsConnection;try {$Login=Add-AzureRmAccount -ServicePrincipal
-TenantId $RunAsConnection.TenantId -ApplicationId $RunAsConnection.ApplicationId -CertificateThumbprint $RunAsConnection.CertificateThumbprint -ErrorAction Stop}catch{Sleep 10;$Login=Add-AzureRmAccount -ServicePrincipal -TenantId $RunAsConnection.TenantId -ApplicationId $RunAsConnection.ApplicationId -CertificateThumbprint $RunAsConnection.CertificateThumbprint};Set-AzureRmContext
-SubscriptionId $RunAsConnection.SubscriptionID
```

Then, I have to modify it manually to below code and it works.

```
$RunAsConnection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name AzureRunAsConnection;try {$Login=Add-AzureRmAccount -ServicePrincipal -TenantId $RunAsConnection.TenantId -ApplicationId $RunAsConnection.ApplicationId -CertificateThumbprint $RunAsConnection.CertificateThumbprint -ErrorAction Stop}catch{Sleep 10;$Login=Add-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -TenantId $RunAsConnection.TenantId -ApplicationId $RunAsConnection.ApplicationId -CertificateThumbprint $RunAsConnection.CertificateThumbprint};Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $RunAsConnection.SubscriptionID
```

How to fix this and how to force the automation account to use Az instead of Azure RM ?

Thanks!

Comment: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/az-modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/az-modules)

Comment: Hello, if the answer is helpful, could you please help accept it as answer? Thanks.

Comment: The link from @RoadRunner is dead.

Answer (score 3):

After [import Az module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/az-modules#import-the-az-modules), you can use `Connect-AzAccount` for authentication, then use other `Az` cmdlet directly.

An example is using `Get-AzWebApp`(need to import `Az.Websites` modules as mentioned before) to get azure web app details, in automation runbook:

```
$connection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name AzureRunAsConnection
$connectionResult = Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant $connection.TenantID -ApplicationId $connection.ApplicationID -CertificateThumbprint $connection.CertificateThumbprint

#the cmdlet to get azure web app details
Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName xxx
```